# API query/result (json) in php

Tags: php, json, curl

Let me preface this by stating that I'm a complete novice when it comes to php, but I have a need to create a php script for a particular curl request to monitor the state of a service.

The curl command is:

```
curl --insecure --digest 'https://admin:password@localhost:9993/management' --header "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"operation":"read-attribute","name":"server-state","json.pretty":1}'
```

And it returns this output:

```
"outcome" : "success",
"result" : "running"
```

I've searched around, found some examples and hacked together a few different scripts but none of them give me the desired result (entirely my fault).  I seem to have the authentication side working but I'm failing miserably at sending the array and returning a result.  Essentially, I'm interested in getting the "running" field back (or whatever other value it might return) which I can use in out monitoring system.  The closest I've got is for the server to throw a java ioexception at me because of an invalid character.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Mark J.

Comment: There are many other questions you can find with "convert cli curl to php".

Comment: Sometimes all it takes is persistence (and a lot of help from Google).  The bit I was missing was to json_encode my query string.  Looks good now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Never mind.  I needed to json_encode my data string.  All working now.